# JSON parse to populate listview Android Studio

Tags: json, parsing

I am pulling my hair out over this. After numerous tutorials, I thought I found the perfect one (7th to be exact. But after following the tutorial, I found out that JSONparse is deprecated. Can someone please give me a solution for this. I just want to read an array from the url and populate a listview.

The array is:

```
{ "lotInfo":[{"lot":"A","spaces":"198","rates":"3.25"},  
{"lot":"B","spaces":"165","rates":"7.50"}]}
```

MainActivity.Java:

```
package com.example.sahan.wtf;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private Context context;
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.199/get_info.php";

private static final String lot = "lot";
private static final String spaces = "spaces";
private static final String rates = "rates";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ListView lv ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
}


private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {

        Log.i("1", "Called");
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.list_activity, new String[] { lot, spaces, rates }, new int[] { R.id.lot, R.id.spaces, R.id.rates });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lv = getListView();

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JSONParse jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String vlot = c.getString(lot);

                String vspaces = c.getString(spaces);
                String vrates = c.getString(rates);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(lot, vlot);
                map.put(spaces, vspaces);
                map.put(rates, vrates);


                jsonlist.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

}


}
```

JSONParser.Java:

```
package com.example.sahan.wtf;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Error....", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return array;

}
}
```

The error I get is:
Error:(74, 13) error: cannot find symbol class JSONParse

Comment: You need to cut this down to a [mcve].  No one want to go through two hundred lines of code just because you don't want to pinpoint the error.

Comment: I'm not asking you to go through 200 lines of code. I was simply looking for someone to assist me as I'm new to app development. If you don't want to look at it, then please do not waste your time commenting. Jeez.... My questions are aimed towards the community that's actually willing to help out a newbie rather that get ranted on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a typo, instead of:

```
JSONParse jParser = new JSONParser();
```

Should be:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
```

Comment: oh that's embarrassing. Nonetheless I appreciate the help. Although my code still doesn't seem to work and I am wondering if you can take a look at it?